# Как получить значения одной ячейки

Tags: php, mysql

ситуация следующая, есть запрос в БД который возвращает одну ячейку. В самой БД он работает отлично, но вот в PHP ни как не могу его принять.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = "47" AND `meta_key`= "Ссылк"
```

Подскажите, как получить значение именно одной ячейки, ни массива, ни строки, а одной конкретной ячейки, спасибо.

P.S. Пробовал получать строку

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key`= "Ссылк"
```

А после обрабатывать её кодом

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['meta_value'];                        
}
```

Но всё равно результата никакого - белый экран.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта магия мне помогла, решить вопрос.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = "47" AND `meta_key`= "Ссылк"',$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $fr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $frdata = $fr['meta_value'];
        echo $frdata;
}
else echo "Ошибка! Логин или пароль введен неверно!<br>";
```

Возможно кто-то в будущем будет искать и благодаря этому сможет разобраться